# Excel VBA range

Tags: vba, excel

For the below code, the range that I have set does not seem to come out. 
Basically I want to concatenate the values from A2 to A23. My data goes to cell A24.

I've name cell A24 as "WrapNarrEnd" as sometimes I want to add extra rows so I want "WrapNarrEnd" to be constant. I tried using offset value to get to cell one before "WrapNarrEnd" Everything works until the second last line and I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can someone help me out?

```
Function ConcatMe(Rng As Range) As String
    Dim cl As Range
    ConcatMe = ""
    For Each cl In Rng
        ConcatMe = ConcatMe & " " & cl.Text
    Next cl
End Function
```

---

```
Sub test2()
    Dim WrapNarrative As Range
    Dim WrapEnd As Range
    Set WrapEnd = Sheets("CA Sweeps").Range("WrapNarrEnd").Offset(-1, 0)
    **Set WrapNarrative = Sheets("CA Sweeps").Range("A2:wrapnarrend")**
    Sheets("CA Sweeps").Range("I24").Value = ConcatMe(WrapNarrative)
End Sub
```

**Sample Image:**

[image]

Comment: What you you mean by the double star notation in the code? Removing the double makes the code work for me,

Comment: Sorry Jeanno, I added in the double star to indicate where i think the code breaks.

When I tried running the whole script, I receive "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range".

Answer (score 2):

Syntax of the range reference is wrong. You need `Range(<TopLeftCell>, <BottomRightCell>)`

Also, your `ConactMe` function can be imporved.

Here's your code, refactored

```
Function ConcatMe(Rng As Range, Optional Sep As String = vbNullString) As String
    Dim dat As Variant

    If Rng.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        dat = Application.Transpose(Rng.Value)
        ConcatMe = Join(dat, Sep )
    ElseIf Rng.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        dat = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Rng.Value))
        ConcatMe = Join(dat, Sep )
    Else
        ' what do you want to do now?
    End If
End Function


Sub test2()
    Dim WrapNarrative As Range
    Dim WrapEnd As Range

    With Sheets("CA Sweeps")
        Set WrapEnd = .Range("WrapNarrEnd").Offset(-1, 0)
        Set WrapNarrative = .Range("A2", "wrapnarrend")
        .Range("I24").Value = ConcatMe(WrapNarrative, " ")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set WrapNarrative = .Range("A2", "wrapnarrend")` will work just fine I think.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the improved concatenate. I tried running the whole script but received "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range". I am not sure whys that.

Comment: @Jackson On which line?

Comment: @Chris. Sorry my bad, pasted in correctly. All good now. Cheers.